# Spring 2.5 Hibernate 3.5 NamedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, named-query

I do not use HibernateTemplate, but work with getCurrentSession() in my DAO.

I would like to know how to declare Hibernate named queries in a beans.xml file (I do not use hbm.xml).

And maybe Spring has alternative means to declare Hibernate named queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put named queries on the entity using annotations:

```
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="Entity.findAll", query="....")})
```

Also, if using JPA, there's `orm.xml`, The [XSD](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd) tells us that you can use:

```
<named-query name="Entity.findAll">
   <query><![CDATA[SELECT e FROM Entity e]]</query>
</named-query>
```

Comment: @Bozho Well I do not use orm.xml as I said. You can put all your hibernate settings, including mapping classes directly to spring beans.xml file. So I wonder how to put a named query THERE. But @NamesQueries annotation looks better, where do you put it? Right into DAO code?

Comment: Put it on the entity class. And you said you don't use hbm.xml, not orm.xml. I somehow assumed you are using JPA xml files (because beans.xml isn't the default name in spring).